# Coinbase OAuth app: Is there a way to grant access to all accounts

Tags: ios, coinbase-api

I am writing an app that would allow a user to authenticate via OAuth against Coinbase and fetch all the account balances. I have created an oAuth app on Coinbase portal and integrated the "official-sdk" pod into my app. However, when I try fetching accounts I only get my BTC account returned. When I use client id/secret from the demo app, I seem to get all of my accounts. Also, when I use client id/secret of the example app I get to retrieve all of my accounts.

Is there some sort of settings tweaking that I am missing for my Oath coinbase app?

Comment: Solved. This is due to 'account' param not being provided in the URL for OAuth authentication page. (more on this here https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/coinbase-connect/permissions)

I had to enhance coinbase-idk to include this param. Anyone knows how I can contribute to coinbase sdk project?

Comment: Perhaps can contribute here? https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-ios-sdk

Also, since you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an answer so that it will be useful for future SO users.

Comment: Wow, really should've checked back on this question... solved this independently over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857809/how-to-request-access-to-all-of-the-user-accounts-using-walletaccountsread/48031203#48031203